# etoolbox and tabularx -- problem with `appto`

Tags: tabularx, etoolbox

I'm trying to print worksheets. I have already implemented an automatic numbering for subtasks. I use `tabularx` for my subtasks (see the MWE below).

Yesterday, I tried to define a new macro called `\task` that has one optional argument which is the amount of points you can obtain for this particular question. I would like these optional arguments to be gathered with `etoolbox`'s `\appto` command so that I can print them with my `\credits` command.

So far, this seems to be ind of struggling as `tabularx` is working on the tables several times. Every time `tabularx` calculates the width of `X` columns the points are appended to `\credits` which leads to an incorrect list of points.

Is there any way I can solve this problem? I'm currently stucked with this issue.

Plus, I don't know why my `\task` command does work. Why is the counter `subtask` not affected by `tabularx`'s several trials?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\def\credits{}
\newcounter{subtask}
\setcounter{subtask}{1}
\renewcommand{\thesubtask}{\alph{subtask})}
\newcommand{\task}[1][]{%
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{%
        \thesubtask%
        \stepcounter{subtask}%
    }{%
        \thesubtask%
        \gappto\credits{(#1)}%
        \stepcounter{subtask}%
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[l]{l@{\hspace*{1ex}}X}
    \task[1]    &   TEXT1\\
    \task       &   TEXT2\\
    \task[3]    &   TEXT3
\end{tabularx}
\credits
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The solution given by David Carlisle below causes a table that is too wide. How can this be undone?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[a6paper, showframe=true]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\def\credits{}
\newcounter{subtask}
\setcounter{subtask}{1}
\renewcommand{\thesubtask}{\alph{subtask})}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\task}[1][]{%
    \ifx\hfuzz\@tempdima%
%   % tabularx trial do nothing
    \else%
        \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{%
            \thesubtask%
            \stepcounter{subtask}%
        }{%
            \thesubtask%
                \gappto\credits{(#1 BE)\\}%
            \stepcounter{subtask}%
        }%
    \fi
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[l]{l@{\hspace*{1ex}}X}
    \task[1]    &   Some longer text that exceedes the line width.\\
    \task[4]    &   TEXT2\\
    \task[3]    &   TEXT3
\end{tabularx}
\credits

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will ask a new question for this. The original problem has been solved.

Comment: I will ask a new question for this. The original problem has been solved. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/511681/164672

Comment: I fixed the answer here sorry then voted to close that one as a duplicate (or you could delete it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your final question first. `tabularx` takes special care not to over-increment latex counters, but it can not by default handle other kinds of side effects that may get executed during the trials. (LaTeX maintains  a global structure for resetting counter values mainly for the `\includeonly` system so counters can be reset after omitted sections, and `tabularx` "borrows" that.

However tabularx does disable other things during trials so you can test for a trial run and do nothing, here I test for `\hfuzz` having a non standard definition only used during trials:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\def\credits{}
\newcounter{subtask}
\setcounter{subtask}{1}
\renewcommand{\thesubtask}{\alph{subtask})}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\task}[1][]{%
    \ifx\hfuzz\@tempdima 
     \thesubtask
     \else
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{%
        \thesubtask%
        \stepcounter{subtask}%
    }{%
        \thesubtask%
        \gappto\credits{(#1)}%
        \stepcounter{subtask}%
    }%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[l]{l@{\hspace*{1ex}}X}
    \task[1]    &   TEXT1\\
    \task       &   TEXT2\\
    \task[3]    &   TEXT3
\end{tabularx}
\credits
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I looked through the `tabularx` code to find some `if` commands that may be the solution, but I didn't try this one. Thank you for your quick response!

Comment: @rsa-krypto answer updated so it sets the task number in trial runs