# tabularx too wide (after using etoolbox's appto?)

Tags: tabularx, etoolbox

After using the solution of another problem (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/511191/164672)), my `tabularx` table is too wide now. Please see the MWE and its output below.

Adding `\noindent` before the first table doesn't help (as suggested in one of the comments [above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/511191/164672)).

Setting the table width to `\dimexpr\linewidth-\parindent` does help a bit, but still the table is slightly too wide (`.92703pt`).

When I don't use my `\task` command the table is just fine. As far as I can see this issue is caused by the definition of `\task`.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[a6paper, showframe=true]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\def\credits{}
\newcounter{subtask}
\setcounter{subtask}{1}
\renewcommand{\thesubtask}{\alph{subtask})}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\task}[1][]{%
    \ifx\hfuzz\@tempdima%
%   % tabularx trial do nothing
    \else%
        \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{%
            \thesubtask%
            \stepcounter{subtask}%
        }{%
            \thesubtask%
                \gappto\credits{(#1 BE)\\}%
            \stepcounter{subtask}%
        }%
    \fi
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[l]{>{\bfseries}l@{\hspace*{1ex}}X@{}}
    \task[1]    &   Some longer text that exceedes the line width. Some longer text that exceedes the line width. Some longer text that exceedes the line width.\\
    \task[3]    &   TEXT2
\end{tabularx}
\credits

\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\parindent}[l]{>{\bfseries}l@{\hspace*{1ex}}X@{}}
    \task[1]    &   Some longer text that exceedes the line width. Some longer text that exceedes the line width. Some longer text that exceedes the line width.\\
    \task[3]    &   TEXT2
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[l]{>{\bfseries}l@{\hspace*{1ex}}X@{}}
    a)  &   Some longer text that exceedes the line width. Some longer text that exceedes the line width. Some longer text that exceedes the line width.\\
    b)  &   TEXT2
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding `\thesubtask` before the comment about trial run

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this as duplicate the answer I posted before is wrong, @egreg probably has the right fix but I'm probably offline for a bit, if either of you want to fix the posted answer feel free or I'll do it later