# calculator does nor work in evironments

Tags: pdftex

Why does the `calculator` not work in environments?

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{calculator}

\newcommand{\resetinvoicesum}{\ADD{0}{0}{\invoicesum}}
\newcommand{\addtoinvoicesum}[1]{\ADD{\invoicesum}{#1}{\invoicesum}}

\begin{document}
    
    \resetinvoicesum

    \begin{tabular}{l}
        
        15.78\addtoinvoicesum{15.78}\\
        15.89\addtoinvoicesum{15.89}\\
        sum:\invoicesum
    
    \end{tabular}

    ~\\
    15.78\addtoinvoicesum{15.78}\\
    15.89\addtoinvoicesum{15.89}\\
    sum:\invoicesum
    
\end{document}
```

This leads to:

[image]

Is that related to the problem with settings lengths in environments?
How do I fix it?

Comment: It is probably not environments, but rather the fact that cells  are groups, so unless `\ADD` does a global assignment you will never get the result you are after

Comment: You need `\newcommand{\addtoinvoicesum}[1]{\ADD{\invoicesum}{#1}{\invoicesum}\GLOBALCOPY{\invoicesum}{\invoicesum}}`

Comment: @Marijn: Please add that as an answer and I will accept it. It works!

Comment: @Marijn: But it does not work with `tabularx`. Somehow the result is 2 or 3 times higher than expected...

Comment: @mrCarnivore that was not your question :) however, this is a known issue, tabularx processes the contents of the table multiple times (each time executing the `\ADD` statements) in order to get the layout right. There was a recent question about that, using a different calculation package but the same overall issue, let me see if I can find that.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227142/tabularx-processes-its-body-multiple-times-how-do-i-know-which-cycle-i-am-in?noredirect=1&lq=1 describes the issue (and a workaround), it is not the one I was looking for but it is still relevant here.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511191/etoolbox-and-tabularx-problem-with-appto/511224#511224 is a bit more complete regarding the code provided in the answer.

Comment: @Marijn: Thank you. Sometimes I find a minimal example that shows the same behaviour than my original problem but the solution does not fit to the more complicated problem. I guess you have to understand the limits of LaTeX quite a bit to be able to frame a good minimal example. The solution you linked to seems to look fitting but is quite complex and needs to be adapted. I'll try to figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're tied to `calculator`, then define a `\GADD` command for “global addition”, because alignment cells form groups and `calculator` does local assignments.

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{calculator}

\newcommand{\GADD}[3]{%
  \ADD{#1}{#2}{\tmpcalc}\global\let#3\tmpcalc
}

\newcommand{\resetinvoicesum}{\GADD{0}{0}{\invoicesum}}
\newcommand{\addtoinvoicesum}[1]{\GADD{\invoicesum}{#1}{\invoicesum}}

\begin{document}

\resetinvoicesum

\begin{tabular}{l}
  15.78\addtoinvoicesum{15.78}\\
  15.89\addtoinvoicesum{15.89}\\
  sum: \invoicesum
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

With “more modern” tools:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\resetfpvar}{m}
 {
  \fp_zero_new:c { g_carnivore_fpvar_#1_fp }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtofpvar}{mm}
 {% #1 = var name, #2 = amount
  \fp_gadd:cn { g_carnivore_fpvar_#1_fp } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\printfpvar}{m}
 {
  \fp_use:c { g_carnivore_fpvar_#1_fp }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\newcommand{\resetinvoicesum}{\resetfpvar{invoicesum}}
\newcommand{\addtoinvoicesum}[1]{\addtofpvar{invoicesum}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\resetinvoicesum

\begin{tabular}{l}
  15.78\addtoinvoicesum{15.78}\\
  15.89\addtoinvoicesum{15.89}\\
  sum: \printfpvar{invoicesum}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that alternative solution. In my real problem I want to use `tabularx` with which even the your alternative solution does not work. Do you also have an easy solution for that? Or should I ask a new question for that?