# Macro Inspected with \show Command Isn't Properly Evaluated

Tags: tabularx, datatool

I'm building a class which can read a CSV file and output an invoice document using `datatool` and `tabularx`.

```
% file "invoice.cls"

...

\newcommand \invoice{
  % load invoice table database
  \DTLloadrawdb{invoicedb}{\invoicefile}

  % generate invoice table
  \begin{table}

    \newcommand \amount{\$0}
    \newcommand \amounttotal{\$0}
    \newcommand \hourstotal{0.0}

    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lXrrr}
      \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Rate} & \textbf{Hour(s)} & \textbf{Amount} \\ \hline
      \DTLforeach{invoicedb}{\date=Date,\description=Description,\rate=Rate,\hours=Hours}{%
        \DTLgmul{\amount}{\rate}{\hours}%
        \DTLgadd{\amounttotal}{\amount}{\amounttotal}%

        % table row
        \date &
        \description &
        \DTLround{\v}{\rate}{2}\v &
        \DTLround{\v}{\hours}{1}\v &
        \DTLround{\v}{\amount}{2}\v \\

        \DTLiflastrow{\hline}{}%
      }

      \DTLground{\amounttotal}{\amounttotal}{2}%
      \DTLsumcolumn{invoicedb}{Hours}{\hourstotal}%

      %\show \amounttotal
      %\show \hourstotal
      & & \textbf{Total:} &
      \hourstotal &
      \amounttotal

    \end{tabularx}
  \end{table}
}

...
```

This nearly works as intended; however, the summed values `\hourstotal` and `\amounttotal` do not evaluate how I expect them to.

Uncommenting each of the `\show` commands:

```
$ pdflatex invoice.tex

...

> \amounttotal=macro:
->\$655.20.
<inserted text> ...total }\par \show \amounttotal
                                                  & & \textbf {Total:} & \ho...
l.5   \invoice

...
```

and again

```
$ pdflatex invoice.tex

...

> \hourstotal=macro:
->23.400000000.
<inserted text> ...stotal }\par \show \hourstotal
                                                  & & \textbf {Total:} & \ho...
l.5   \invoice

...
```

These values are **correct**. I expect to have a total amount of `$655.20` and a total hours of `23.4`.

However, when they are evaluated *the very next line after*, the actual values generated are `$1,965.60` total amount and `0.0` hours.

[image: invoice table with hours and amount columns]

I find it absolutely bizzare that the `\amounttotal` value is exactly three times larger than the value as seen by the `\show` command while at the same time the `\totalhours` value seems to have been lost.

Any help on this is much appreciated. Please let me know if there is any other critical information I should include in trying to debug this problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But `\DTLg…` work globally. So IMHO the main problem here is, that `tabularx` has to process (some) rows multiply, to get the column widths etc. See your own answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511224/277964).

Comment: sorry I misread your question (I was looking on my phone:-), it is not grouping but tabularx re-evaluating. You could do the DTL commands only on the final pass, or more simply use `tabular*` not `tabulax` and replace X by p{something}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [cabohah](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/277964/cabohah) and [David Charlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle), I was able to come up with this solution by using `tabular` rather than `tabularx`:

```
...
    \begin{tabular}{lp{3.2in}rrr}
      \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Rate} & \textbf{Hour(s)} & \textbf{Amount} \\ \hline
      \DTLforeach{invoicedb}{\date=Date,\description=Description,\rate=Rate,\hours=Hours}{%
        \DTLgmul{\amount}{\rate}{\hours}%
        \DTLgadd{\amounttotal}{\amount}{\amounttotal}%
        \DTLgadd{\hourstotal}{\hours}{\hourstotal}%

        % table row
        \date &
        \description &
        \DTLround{\v}{\rate}{2}\v &
        \DTLround{\v}{\hours}{1}\v &
        \DTLround{\v}{\amount}{2}\v \\

        \DTLiflastrow{\hline}{}%
      }

      % table footer
      & & \textbf{Total:} &
      \DTLround{\v}{\hourstotal}{1}\v &
      \DTLround{\v}{\amounttotal}{2}\v

    \end{tabular}
...
```

To reiterate the problem I was facing (as best I understand it), `tabularx` needs to re-evaluate the table multiple times when choosing the appropriate cell width for the cell positioning character 'X'.